# TCPServer Class NameError in RubyMotion (OSX)

Tags: macos, rubymotion

I have some code I am porting over to RubyMotion from MacRuby and I'm getting a TCPServer Name error: Here is the error message:

```
app_delegate.rb:29:in `control_server:': uninitialized constant AppDelegate::TCPServer (NameError)
```

This is the line of code that causes the problem:

```
dts = TCPServer.new(ip, port)
```

I have read that some classes from Ruby aren't included in RubyMotion but I'm not sure which classes and how to determine which classes aren't available.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RubyMotion doesn't include the entire Ruby standard library because RubyMotion doesn't come with a built-in way to deal with certain parts of the Ruby language that are required by lots of the standard library and community gems - such as `require`, `eval`, `load` and so on.

Traditionally, we've dealt with this by using *Objective-C* libraries instead, since RubyMotion bridges Objective-C classes seamlessly.  There's a wealth of existing Objective-C libraries out there and a fabulous dependency management system in [CocoaPods](http://www.rubymotion.com/developer-center/articles/cocoapods/).  If you're down for a little rewriting, the [CocoaAsyncSocket](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/CocoaAsyncSocket/7.3.1/) library should suit your needs.

If you're feeling a little more adventurous, you could try getting your existing code working by using [MotionBundler](http://blog.rubymotion.com/post/50983350225/motionbundler-good-old-fashioned-requirements-for).  It attempts to add `require` support to RubyMotion, with varying levels of success.  In theory, you'd simply put back that `require 'socket'` line in your code after you've set up MotionBundler and it should take care of the rest.  I got some pretty scary-looking stack traces when I tried it myself though, so it's probably not a silver bullet.  `TCPServer` is particularly worrying since I'm fairly sure it uses native C extensions, which are not supported by MotionBundler.

Comment: Thanks Aethe. I will give motion bundler a try but will probably start looking at the Cocoa sockets.

Comment: I tried motionbundler and it didn't like the socket library as you suspected.